# add notification badges to a mat-tab

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, badge, mat-tab

I am trying to add notification badge to a mat-tab 
similar to the image below ,

[notification badge on top right of the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXvju.png)

But I can't seem to find a way to do it on angular material tabs. Since the badges are being cut.

Here is a stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqlmkb-zzkrtg

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 31):

You can create a custom label template for a mat-tab and put icons/badges etc in the label.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span matBadge="4" matBadgeOverlap="false">Label with Badge</span>
    </ng-template>
    Content
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the MatBadgeModule to the imports in app.module.ts and this will work